# Install WebSvn to use an Invalid SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, svn, visualsvn-server

Im trying to Install WebSvn on my server but the repositories im trying to connect to have a self signed certificate so websvn is unable to connect.

> Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

Is there some sort of setting im missing in setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know websvn, but your problem is: the self-signed certificate is not trusted.

do you get this message in your browser or on the server?

when in the browser, import your self-signed as trusted to the browser cert store. when it is on the server, try to add [SSLCACertificateFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile) to your apache config.

Comment: Yeh i get that same message when viewing the Repo in either a browser or tortiosesvn but they have the ability to accept it anyway. I dont wuite understand how i go about adding the cerfificate file to my apache config, can you help me out with this?

Comment: this blog post gives you a step-by-step guide: http://blog.laimbock.com/2007/08/28/svn-and-websvn-over-ssl-with-self-signed-certificates/